# nginx ingress - multiple ingress objects having server-snippet annotation, not merged in nginx config

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have 2 different ingress objects each having different snippet for server config.

Object 1:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* "^/service1/endpoint(/|$)(.*)" { 
        deny all; 
        return 403; 
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  name: Ingress1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service: 
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /service1/endpoint(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Object 2:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* "^/service2/endpoint(/|$)(.*)" { 
        deny all; 
        return 403; 
      }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  name: Ingress2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service: 
            name: service2
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /service2/endpoint(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

When I apply the 2nd Object, I get this error:

```
 controller.go:1172] Server snippet already configured for server "example.com", skipping (Ingress "default/Ingress2")
```

If I open the nginx.conf from the controller pod, I see only the server-snippet from Ingress1.

Can multiple server-snippets merge on the same host?

Comment: cant you merge both ingress?

Comment: Each ingress is created from different repos from different pipelines. So, cant merge them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet` annotation can only be used once per host ([reference](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet)).

Comment: This is an aside, but your `spec.rules` and server snippet contain the same regex patterns for each service.  I'm guessing this isn't intentional as it will end up producing duplicate regex location blocks for each service.